# Перемещение курсора на позицию кнопки Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо переместить курсор в позицию кнопки, использую следующий код:

```
connect(ui->startButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]()
    {
        ui->fixTimeButton->setHidden(false);
        QCursor::setPos(mapToGlobal(ui->fixTimeButton->pos()));
        ui->startButton->setEnabled(false);
    });
```

После нажатия на кнопку Start, курсор перемещается, но не на точное положение кнопки (красная точка на картинке - положение курсора,черный квадрат - нужная кнопка).
Откуда берется это смещение и как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У курсора обычно координаты экранные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко, то ответ:

```
QCursor::setPos(ui->tab->mapToGlobal(ui->fixTimeButton->pos())); // считаем что "Tab1" называется tab
```

А теперь детальнее.

Читаем маны по QWidget

> QPoint QWidget::mapToGlobal(const QPoint &pos) const Translates the
> widget coordinate pos to global screen coordinates.

Т.е. QWidget::mapToGlobal возвращает глобальные экранные координаты для чилдрена этого самого QWidget.

Если бы ваш fixTimeButton располагался непосредственно на форме, ваш код бы сработал, но кнопка находится на вкладке, вкладка в табвиджете. Это и есть ваше смещение.. Т.е.

```
    // Ваш вариант
    qDebug()<<mapToGlobal(ui->pushButton->pos()); // Запись аналогична this->mapToGlobal(...)
    // Правильный вариант
    qDebug()<<ui->tab->mapToGlobal(ui->pushButton->pos());
    // А теперь посмотрим на сколько вы ошиблись
    qDebug()<<ui->tab->mapToGlobal(ui->pushButton->pos())-mapToGlobal(ui->pushButton->pos());
```